# Adding custom ValueProviderFactories to ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, protobuf-net

I was looking to try and add a Protobuf ValueProviderFactory to MVC3 so that I could pick out the MIME type and deserialize the raw data into objects for action parameters. I could also use this to change the default Json serializer.

Looking at `JsonValueProviderFactory.cs` this shouldn't be too difficult, but the factories all appear to be hard-coded.

For Protobuf I may be able to do something with an IValueProvider but I haven't even checked yet what MVC3 does when it recieves an MIME type of `application/x-protobuf`.

Am I going about this the right way?

**UPDATE**

I found [this](http://mgolchin.net/posts/19/dive-deep-into-mvc-ivalueprovider) blog post that talks about creating an `IValueProvider`. It then mentions at the bottom that this changed around MCV2. He changed it to a `ValueProviderFactory` and calls :

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new HttpCookieValueProviderFactory());
```

But in MVC3 this property is read only.

Comment: Interesting. I don't know about what MVC does here, so I'll be following this question with curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that it is not read only and you can add providers as follows:

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new MyValueProviderFactory());
```

I would have know this had I checked myself!

I've done some more searching today, and [this](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt8-value-providers.html) blog post seems to suggest that the `DependencyResolver` will find any classes that inherit `ValueProviderFactory`. I'm using MEF for dependency resolution so I can just add an Export attribute and it'll get picked up automatically.

I now have a [further issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902885/creating-mvc3-valueproviderfactories-that-require-type-information) writing a custom ValueProviderFactory for protobuf-net.

Comment: You can also remove value providers if you want to do something like swap the default json value provider wtih a custom one.